# deserialize json field into plain string with gson

Tags: java, gson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a json object into a java bean. 
The main issue I am facing is that I'd like to treat the field `object` of the json string as a plain string, even if it contains a potentially correct json object. 
The json structure is like this:

```
{
    "type":"user",
    "object":{
        "id":"1", 
        ...}
}
```

How can i tell gson to ignore the `object` value so that it doesn't get deserialized into an object? I'd like it only to be mapped to a plain `String` field in my bean so that I can dispose a proper deserialization for it, once I got the type from the `type` field.

Comment: i managed to partially deserialize the object watching this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769473/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-json-using-gson-when-the-element-to-parse-is-an/4455636#4455636

Answer (score 12):

Just declare it as of type JsonObject

```
class ExampleJsonModel {
    @SerializedName("type")
    public String type;

    @SerializedName("object")
    public JsonObject object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your problem is solved. I ran into a similar question and here it is how I worked it out:

**JsonDeserializer** allows you to make you own adapter to deserialize that **:

```
class JavaBeanDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<JavaBeanObject>() {
    public JavaBeanObject fromJson(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    // return JavaBeanObject built using your logic.
}
```

You've to register *JavaBeanDeserializer* to Gson object when building it:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(JavaBeanObject.class, new JavaBeanDeserializer()).create();
```

Comment: didn't try your solution, but solved this with the link in the previous comment